# Oracle check constraint, call function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am trying to query a table(wishlist_table) to see how many times a member appears in it.

The business rule I am trying to implement is that a member can have at most five items on there wishlist at any one time.

I have been told to do this as a domain constraint so i have created a function to check how many time a membersId appear in the wishlist table but i get an error when calling the from my check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE WishlistTest
(
WishlistId NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CONSTRAINT chk_Wishlist CHECK (sw3.wishListUpToFiveItems() >= 0 AND sw3.wishListUpToFiveItems() < 5)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionWishListUpToFiveItems
RETURN number IS
total number(1) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) into total
FROM Member
WHERE MemberId = 1;

IF total < 5 THEN
    return total;
ELSE RETURN -1;
END IF;
END;
```

If someone could tell me a better way of going about this or see what I am doing wrong it would be great

Comment: In general, if you are getting an error, post the error.  Otherwise, we have to guess and we may guess wrong.  Who told you to implement this as a constraint?  Is this a homework assignment or a request from a supervisor?  Since you cannot call functions from a `CHECK` constraint in Oracle, the entire approach is probably wrong which is why it's useful to know where the constraint "requirement" is coming from.

Comment: This is a college assignment, if i cant call the function from the check constraint ill have to go about it some other way. He has said it can be done as a domain constraint can anyone tell me how to go about it. I dont want the code jut the way to go about it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that your instructor wants you to

- Add an integer column to the table to store the wish list position
- Add a constraint that insures that the combination of member and wish list position is unique
- Add a constraint that limits the wish list position to a value between 1 and 5

For alternate approaches using triggers or materialized views (with a constraint on the materialized view) and probably more discussion about how Oracle should allow some sort of assertion syntax to enforce this sort of constraint, you can look through [this askTom thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4233459000346171405).